# Compute $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{n-1}{n+1})^{\frac{n+1}{n-1}}$

Tags: limits

Compute $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{n-1}{n+1})^{\frac{n+1}{n-1}}$

I did: $\lim_{n\to  \infty}(1+\frac{1}{\frac{n+1}{n-1}})^{\frac{n+1}{n-1}}=e$.

Why is this incorrect?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hint: What is the limit of $(n+1)/(n-1)$ ?

Comment: Because $(n-1)/(n+1) \not\to +\infty$, and you cannot use that significant well-known limit about $\mathrm e$.

Comment: limit of $(n+1)/(n-1)=1$, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope you solved the problem. Here is a fact that might help you.

Put, $t=\frac{n+1}{n-1}$. Here as $n\to \infty$, $t=\frac{n+1}{n-1}=\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}}{1-\frac{1}{n}}\to 1$. Putting all these we get, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{n-1}{n+1})^{\frac{n+1}{n-1}}= \lim_{t\to 1}(1+\frac{1}{t})^t=2$$